# Problems with biblatex' \DeclareLanguageMapping after update

Tags: biblatex

I recently updated my MiKTeX including `biblatex` (v3.11) and now I am getting strange results when using a custom language file, e.g. given the example below:
`Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'volume' untranslated`

The result looks like

[image]

This has worked perfectly before and it still works when removing the line `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-myveryown}` from the `bbx` file.

I am not aware of an internal `biblatex` change causing this behaviour. Therefore I seek for your expertise.

```
\begin{filecontents}{myveryown.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{myveryown.bbx}[2018/04/24 v1.0 biblatex bibliography style]
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authortitle}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-myveryown}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ngerman-myveryown.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{ngerman-myveryown.lbx}[2018/04/24 v1.0 biblatex localization]
\InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
   byeditor = {{herausgegeben von}{hgg\adddotspace v\adddot}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{abibfile.bib}
@book{akey,
address = {Zürich and Wiesbaden},
edition = {My very own edition},
title = {A very long title},
volume = {1},
publisher = {My publisher},
author = {Author, An},
year = {1999},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[bibstyle=myveryown]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{abibfile.bib}
\begin{document}
Test\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.lbx` should `inherit` its strings from `ngerman` as well

```
\ProvidesFile{ngerman-myveryown.lbx}[2018/04/24 v1.0 biblatex localization]
\InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
   inherit  = {ngerman},
   byeditor = {{herausgegeben von}{hgg\adddotspace v\adddot}},
}
```

The loading and internal handling of `.lbx` files was overhauled in version 3.11 (see the [Release notes in the Wiki](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki#release-notes-for-version-311), [CHANGES.md](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/CHANGES.md) and the [pull request that implemented this on GitHub](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/702)). What you are seeing seems to be a side-effect of those changes. As far as documented behaviour goes, the version without `inherit  = {ngerman},` should never have worked in the first place, and I'm surprised it did. In particular, §4.11.8 *Custom Localization Modules*, p. 249 of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) states

> Alternative `lbx` files must ensure that the localisation module is complete. They should do so by inheriting data from the corresponding standard module. If the language `american` is mapped to `american-mla.lbx`, `biblatex` will not load `american.lbx` unless this module is requested explicitly. In the above example, inheriting ‘strings’ and ‘extras’ will cause `biblatex` to load `american.lbx`.
>   before applying the modifications in american-mla.lbx.

Comment: Thank you very much. The old versions certainly worked.

I saw the ``inherit`` line in the documentation (it is even printed in blue) for the lbx file, but did not realize, that I  it. Sorry for not seeing that.

Comment: @Martin I thought so, otherwise you would have noticed the problem earlier. There were some weird edge cases with the old behaviour that could mean that this worked even though it should not have worked. It's a bit annoying that we broke things that worked before, but since this was always documented behaviour I hope we can get away with it.