# \DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix, inheritance, and polyglossia in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages, polyglossia

I'm having trouble getting language mapping inheritance working properly in `biblatex` with `\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix` and language variants in `polyglossia`.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{english-test.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit = {english},
  in = {in \textcolor{red}{(english)}}{in \textcolor{red}{(english)}},
  pages = {pages \textcolor{red}{(english)}}{pp\adddot\space\textcolor{red}{(english)}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{american-test.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{american}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit = {american},
  in = {in \textcolor{blue}{(american)}}{in \textcolor{blue}{(american)}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=american]{english}
%\usepackage[american]{babel}% <- works with babel
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-test}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{westfahl:space}
\end{document}
```

It gives the following output (expected, since `biblatex` can't detect language variants with `polyglossia`):

> [image]

If we use `\usepackage[american]{babel}`, we also get the expected (and desired) output:

> [image]

## Question

What do I have to add to the `polyglossia` case to get `biblatex` to load both `american-test.lbx` *and* `english-test.lbx`?

Whatever is added should also work with `babel`.

### Things I've tried:

- `\usepackage[style=verbose,language=american]{biblatex}` (Gets overridden when `polyglossia` is loaded)
- `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-test}` (Never loads `english-test.lbx`)
- `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american}` (Neither loads `american-test.lbx` nor `english-test.lbx`)

Comment: Is 'don't use `polyglossia` until it has an interface to get the language variant (preferable mapped to a `babel` identifier)' an acceptable answer? `\usepackage[language=american]{biblatex}` should not solve your problem since it ideally should force `american` everywhere (could be broken at the moment, I'm investigating). The `\DeclareLanguageMapping`s over language variants are to be avoided: "Note that `\DeclareLanguageMapping` is not intended to handle language variants or `babel`/`polyglossia` language aliases" (p. 294 of the manual).

Comment: BTW: I'd be interested to know what else the new `.lbx` handling broke for you. Until now the transition has been very smooth (apart from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428264/35864 where I could argue for user error). Just open an issue at the `biblatex` bugtracker.

Comment: @moewe, the problem is that `biblatex-sbl` (which this is for) documents almost certainly require Hebrew. And `babel` is not quite there for Hebrew yet :(.

Comment: @moewe, it didn't break much. Mostly my attempts to use `\DeclareLanguageMapping` to deal with variants... I might ask a separate question related to defaulting to `american` conventions when `babel/polyglossia` isn't loaded, but still allowing for `british` when requested by `babel`.

Comment: Bummer. I'm not very hopeful that anything sensible can be done until we get the `polyglossia` support right (which is not happening anytime soon I'm afraid - at least given the current pace of development for `polyglossia`).

Comment: @moewe, With regard to using `language=american`. Both `babel` and `polyglossia` override it. (BTW, this is my current solution to defaulting to `american` I load this option within the style and users can override if they want when they load `babel/polyglossia`... I think you are about to break this for me :) )

Comment: Yeah, scrap the comment about `language=american` not working. It is actually documented behaviour that one has to use a `autolang` different from `none` to get its effects properly. I'm not going to touch it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77734/discussion-between-david-purton-and-moewe).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Update** All multilingual features of `biblatex` should work as intended with `biblatex` v3.14 (or above) and `polyglossia` v1.46 (or above).
>
> The MWE from the question produces the expected (`babel`-equivalent) output now.
>
> If you are facing any problems with `polyglossia` and `biblatex`, update your system so that you have at least `biblatex` 3.14 (and a matching Biber version) and `polyglossia` 1.46.
>   If that does not help, please open a bug report at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues.
>
> The rest of this answer below is kept for academic purposes.
>
> Note in particular that the bug in `polyglossia` (https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/205) that I opened when formulating this question is resolved.

This is not a full answer, but it describes why things go wrong with `polyglossia` and how the entire language mapping business works.

## `polyglossia` and `biblatex`

The `polyglossia` support in `biblatex` is still patchy at best. My advice would be to avoid `polyglossia` if at all possible and use `babel` instead. `polyglossia` used to be a must-have for certain languages (especially for languages with non-Latin scripts or RTL languages), but recent `babel` development has shown improvements in that matter. For other languages (Western European certainly) there is no huge advantage in choosing `polyglossia` over `babel` (and it has been that way for quite some time).

#### `babel`'s languages vs. `polyglossia` main language+options

The most problematic issue by far is the detection of language variants. While `babel` simply and naively defines a new language for each variant or dialect it encounters, `polyglossia` has a much more sophisticated interface that sets the main language that can then be modified with certain attributes (for example `variant` to turn `english` into `american` or `british` or `german` into `swissgerman` or `austrian`; and `spelling` to select `ngerman` or `german`).

#### Variant detection

Unfortunately, the `variant`/`spelling` variants of a main language have a non-uniform implementation across languages and there is no interface for packages or classes to find out which variant is currently in use. This is a major problem for packages that also want to act upon the language variant. It is actually worse than that, in certain situations not even `polyglossia` knows which variant is active! Take the following contrived example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{dutch}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\def\month{1}% we need january where German German and Austrian German differ
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{english}
\section{\protect\today}
\end{english}

\section{\protect\today}

\begin{german}[variant=austrian]
\section{\protect\textcolor{red}{\protect\today}}
\end{german}

\begin{dutch}
\section{\protect\today}
\end{dutch}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The date changes languages in the TOC in the same way that it changes in the section headers, but it does not change the language variant. I have reported this at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/205

#### Finding out which language to load

`biblatex` mainly works with the `babel` model of treating languages: Every dialect is a new language (there can be inheritance between languages, but that does not really matter for the overall view).
So there would first have to be a proper interface to convert `polyglossia` main languages+options to a `babel` equivalent before `biblatex` can even know what language to load. That conversion is a non-trivial task because there need not be a connection between the way `polygossia` sets up its main language with options and the name `babel` has for the resulting language. I believe that this can only be properly tackled on the `polyglossia` side, because each `gloss-....ldf` essentially has to declare its `babel`-equivalent names. A very rudimentary proof of concept can be found at https://github.com/moewew/polyglossia/tree/bblnames, the changes to the current `polyglossia` version are at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/compare/master...moewew:bblnames.

#### Using the loaded language

Even after the language file is finally loaded, the problems for `biblatex` don't stop. With `babel` the bibstrings are simply added to `\extras<babel-language>`. That command is called whenever the language is switched and so the correct strings are activated. But with `polyglossia` only `\extras<base-language>` exists (there is no `\extrasaustrian` there is only `\extrasgerman`), `biblatex` would have to compute the base language from the `babel` language, all variant changes would have to be made *within* `\extras<main-language>`. But as mentioned above, there is no uniform implementation of the variants, so this requires intimate knowledge of the `gloss-....ldf`s.

## `biblatex`'s language mapping

Since this question is also concerned with language mapping and that changed recently (in version 3.11, see [`CHANGES.md`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/v3.11-ctan/doc/latex/biblatex/CHANGES.md#release-notes-for-version-311)), let me explain how this works now.

Whenever `biblatex` now tries to load an `.lbx` file it tries to resolve the language mapping first.

There are specific language mappings with `\DeclareLanguageMapping{<language>}{<new lbx file>}` and general mappings for all languages with `\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{<suffix>}` that map `<language>.lbx` to `<language><suffix>.lbx`. The specific mapping takes precedence over a general mapping.

`.lbx` files may inherit from other `.lbx` files with `\InheritBibliographyStrings{<lang>}`, `\InheritBibliographyExtras{<lang>}` or using `inherit = {<lang>},` as special 'bibstring' in `\DeclareBibliographyStrings`. `.lbx` files that do not define all strings or extras themselves should always inherit what they don't define from a sensible source (see for example [Problems with biblatex' \DeclareLanguageMapping after update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428264/35864)).

When `biblatex` resolves the inheritance all language mappings are still applied. Only infinite recursion is avoided.

Assume we have a file [`german.lbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx) with all the definitions for German.

The file [`ngerman.lbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/ngerman.lbx) for new orthography rules inherits from `german` and only changes what is necessary, it looks like this (simplified and shortened)

```
\ProvidesFile{ngerman.lbx}

\InheritBibliographyExtras{german}

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit  = {german},
  citedas  = {{im Folgenden zitiert als}{im Folgenden zit\adddotspace als}},
}
```

We also have two files for `\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-dp}`

`german-dp.lbx`

```
\ProvidesFile{german-dp.lbx}

\InheritBibliographyExtras{german}

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit  = {german},
  castle   = {{Schloß}{Schloß}},
}
```

`ngerman-dp.lbx`

```
\ProvidesFile{ngerman-dp.lbx}

\InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit  = {ngerman},
  castle   = {{Schloss}{Schloss}},
}
```

If you now ask `biblatex` to get you *ngerman*, it will recall the language mapping we set up and open `ngerman-dp.lbx` instead. `ngerman-dp.lbx` inherits from *ngerman* and so `ngerman.lbx` is opened (we don't follow the mapping because we don't want to open `ngerman-dp.lbx` and land in an infinite loop). `ngerman.lbx` in term inherits from *german*, this time the mapping is followed and so `german-dp.lbx` is opened. `german-dp.lbx` inherits from *german* and finally `german.lbx` is read. The following list shows the files opened in reverse chronological order, since `inherit` is always the first keyword definitions are overwritten by subsequent files

- `german.lbx`
- `german-dp.lbx`
- `ngerman.lbx`
- `ngerman-dp.lbx`

For *ngerman* you will end up with

```
citedas  = {{im Folgenden zitiert als}{im Folgenden zit\adddotspace als}},% ngerman.lbx
castle   = {{Schloss}{Schloss}},% ngerman-dp.lbx
```

For a weird example assume now that additionally to the above

- `german.lbx` defines `lipsum = {lorem}`
- `ngerman.lbx` defines `lipsum = {ipsum}`
- `german-dp.lbx` defines `lipsum = {dolor}`
- `ngerman-dp.lbx` has no entry for `lipsum`.

What do we end up with for *ngerman* (which by virtue of the mapping is `ngerman-dp.lbx`)? The lists shows that we get 'ipsum', i.e. the definition from `ngerman.lbx`.

I should add that I don't have a strong inclination towards claiming that this chain of inheritance is the correct or at least expected one. But I do feel that the way to set up the `.lbx` files is natural and I so I am prepared to accept the resulting chain of inheritance as natural corollary.

If `ngerman-dp.lbx` inherited from *german-dp* instead we would get the following chain

- `german.lbx` (inherited from `german-dp.lbx`)
- `german-dp.lbx` (inherited from `ngerman-dp.lbx`)
- <strike>`german-dp-dp.lbx`</strike> (`ngerman-dp.lbx` inherits *german-dp*, this is the result of applying the suffix, the file doesn't exist and is ignored after a warning, instead `german-dp.lbx` is loaded)
- `ngerman-dp.lbx`

In particular no definition of `ngerman.lbx` gets read and `german-dp.lbx`
's `lipsum = {dolor}` wins. We end up with

```
citedas  = {{im folgenden zitiert als}{im folgenden zit\adddotspace als}},% german.lbx
castle   = {{Schloss}{Schloss}},% ngerman-dp.lbx
lipsum   = {{dolor}{dolor}},% german-dp.lbx
```

`ngerman-dp.lbx` would have to repeat all definitions from `ngerman.lbx` that it wants to keep.

Comment: Related https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/745

Answer (score 2):

Imho the most important thing when setting up language files is to get the inheritance chain correct. You want to inherit in `american-test` from `american` and from `english-test` but it is unclear which from both should be the direct parent: The file says `american` but the expected output shows that you want `english-test` to win at least for the `pages` field.

I would setup the files so that `english-test` is the direct parent along with a mapping to overcome the deficiencies of polyglossia.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{english-test.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit = {english},
  in = {in \textcolor{red}{(english)}}{in \textcolor{red}{(english)}},
  pages = {pages \textcolor{red}{(english)}}{pp\adddot\space\textcolor{red}{(english)}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{american-test.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english-test}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit = {english-test},
  in = {in \textcolor{blue}{(american)}}{in \textcolor{blue}{(american)}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=american]{english}

%\usepackage[american]{babel}% <- works with babel
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-test}
 \DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-test}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{westfahl:space}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is basically what I used to have before `biblatex` 3.11. However, it doesn't work now. Notice that `american.lbx` never gets loaded and hence `\uspunctuation` (and anything else in `\DeclareBibliographyExtras`) is not used. You end up having to include everything from `american.lbx` into `american-test.lbx`, which is not ideal.