# Output for bibliography translator using biblatex and polyglossia

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

I get some strange behavior when trying to display a translator in my biblography. The german "Übers. v." is set to a a "V" with two dots above it.

I think it happens due to the latin language which is loaded by polyglossia ans which is later needed in the document. If I remove `\setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}` all is fine. But I don't really understand why biblatex doesn't simply use the mainlanguage? Has anyone an idea how this could be solved?

Here's my MWE and my Bibliography file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, pagesize=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{german}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

%Bibliographie und Abbildungen
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test-Biblio}

%BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\nocite{bruni_interpretatione_2008}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And the bib file:

```
@book{bruni_interpretatione_2008,
    Address = {Ottawa},
    Author = {Bruni, Leonardo},
    Date-Added = {2018-08-27 12:05:41 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2018-08-27 12:05:41 +0200},
    File = {Katalog plus - Universit{\"a}tsbibliothek Freiburg:/Users/moritzheffter/Library/Application Support/Zotero/Profiles/yc5solgb.default/zotero/storage/U95MWV98/Results.html:text/html},
    Isbn = {978-2-7603-3037-5},
    Keywords = {Quelle},
    Langid = {german},
    Publisher = {Les Presses de l'Univ. d'Ottawa},
    Series = {Collection {Regards} sur la traduction},
    Title = {De interpretatione recta -- {De} la traduction parfaite},
    Translator = {Le Blanc, Charles},
    Year = {2008}}
```

Comment: Can you add a picture of the output? I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqZnb.png which looks OK. What versions of `biblatex` and `polyglossia` are you running?

Comment: Ahh I see, I compiled with LuaLaTeX. Do you compile with XeLaTeX? This quite probably has to do with https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/172

Comment: Yes you are right it's variant classic in the latin package that causes the problem. I'm compiling with XeLaTeX. And after removing the variant all looks fine. I think I'll simply drop the variant. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You may want to check out whether `babel` instead of `polyglossia` is enough for you. `polyglossia` development has stalled in recent years (case in point: the 100+ unaddressed bug reports on GitHub) and `babel` development got back on track. While `polyglossia` was the go-to recommendation for non-Latin scripts back in the day, `babel` has made some huge improvements there. If you only have German, Latin and Greek, `babel` might well be enough for you. `polyglossia` support in `biblatex` is also not entirely great: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432347/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in `polyglossia` reported in January 2017: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/172 The bug only occurs with XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX is not affected.

`latin.ldf` erroneously sets `\classicuclccodes` (defined as `` \def\classicuclccodes{\lccode`\V=`\u \uccode`\u=`\V} ``) in the current scope whenever the language is loaded with `variant=classic` or `variant=medieval`. But the `\uccode` and `\lccode` should only be redefined within the language extras and should be cleaned up afterwards (like in [`gloss-classiclatin.ldf`](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/blob/5f40be4ac82ad05ebe5c400be38bb5ee57f98e92/tex/gloss-classiclatin.ldf#L115-L134)) so that they only apply to Latin text and not to other languages as well.

Here the problem was that `biblatex` needs `\uppercase`/`\MakeUppercase` for automatic capitalisation of "übers. von" with the wrong settings active the "ü" is converted to a "V" with two dots above.

If you don't need the "U/V" feature of `polyglossia` you can turn it off after you load `latin` with an explicit `variant` option (and indeed every time you explicitly request a Latin `variant`) with `\noclassicuclccodes`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, pagesize=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{german}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}
    \noclassicuclccodes % work around https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/172
    \setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber, isbn=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bruni_interpretatione_2008,
    Address = {Ottawa},
    Author = {Bruni, Leonardo},
    Isbn = {978-2-7603-3037-5},
    Keywords = {Quelle},
    Langid = {german},
    Publisher = {Les Presses de l'Univ. d'Ottawa},
    Series = {Collection {Regards} sur la traduction},
    Title = {De interpretatione recta -- {De} la traduction parfaite},
    Translator = {Le Blanc, Charles},
    Year = {2008}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{bruni_interpretatione_2008}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bruni, Leonardo (2008). De interpretatione recta – De la traduction parfaite. Übers. von Charles Le Blanc. Collection Regards sur la traduction. Ottawa: Les Presses de l’Univ. d’Ottawa.]